# ruby gem require_relative cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, directory

I've looked around online and on SO and most of the answers to this question say that I should be using `require_relative` but I am using it so I don't know what the problem might be. I'm trying to build a ruby gem and my folder structure looks like this

```
--xmlmc-rb/
  --lib/
    --xmlmc-rb/
        api.rb
        interface.rb
        version.rb
      xmlmc-rb.rb
```

Within `xmlmc-rb.rb` I am requiring all three of the files under the `xmlmc-rb/` directory like this

```
require_relative "xmlmc-rb/version"
require_relative "xmlmc-rb/interface"
require_relative "xmlmc-rb/api"
require 'net/http'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'base64'
```

But I keep getting an error

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xmlmc-rb-0.1.1/lib/xmlmc-rb.rb:2:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xmlmc-rb-0.1.1/lib/xmlmc-rb/interface (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xmlmc-rb-0.1.1/lib/xmlmc-rb.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from xmlmc_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

When I manually copy all the files into the main rb file everything works. Initially I thought it was a naming error since the casing of the files under `xmlmc-rb/` weren't uniform, but I fixed that, made them all lowercase names and the same error persists.

Comment: I've unredacted anything. It's not really a big deal to put the name out there anyways.

Comment: It found `version.rb` so something is spelled wrong somewhere.

Comment: I agree but I've copied and pasted those names exactly as they exist in my IDE. As I mentioned in my edit, I thought it was a casing issue because interface.rb was Interface.rb but I fixed that and rebuilt the gem and reinstalled with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by copying everything out of interface.rb deleting the file and recreating it. Strange why that happened.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am the author. And this was the answer to the question. I disagree with your point because this was what fixed my problem and potentially could fix others

Comment: Add details to your answer because it is useful for people who has your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't understand very well your gem name, I will show you how I did:

```
require "password_control/scrypt/ScryptHash"
```

In my case I have another directory inside the password_control folder. But if my file was in the password_control directory, the require would be:

```
require "password_control/ScryptHash"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error [building a Ruby Gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/).
I built and installed the gem:

```
gem build <gemname>.gemspec
gem install <gemname>-0.0.1.gem
```

I checked where the gem was installed:

```
gem env home
gem list -d
```

I tried to load the gem in Interactive Ruby (IRB):

```
irb
require '<gemname>'
```

It resulted in error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/<gemname>-0.0.1/lib/my_gem_subdirectory/module_name
```

I was using `require_relative './my_gem_subdirectory/module_name'` in Ruby files in the lib directory to import modules and classes from the sub-directories.

I solved the error by updating the Gemspec .gemspec to include all files and subdirectories. Initially I only had `s.files = ['lib/<gemname>.rb']`. But I read the documentation http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files and changed it to:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  ...
  s.files       = ['lib/discrete_math.rb']
  s.files       += Dir['lib/*.rb']
  s.files       += Dir['lib/my_gem_subdirectory/**/*']
  ...
end
```